# Recorrer directorio y comparar sus archivos con los de otro directorio C#

Tags: c#, rutas, file

Tengo que coger los archivos de un directorio uno a uno y buscar en otro directorio un archivo con el mismo nombre. Una vez coincidan, tengo que llamar a `mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades()` pasando como parámetros sus paths. Mi código es este:

```
     static void recorrerDirectoriosYCompararPorFicheros(string dir1, string dir2)
     {
         System.IO.DriveInfo dirOrigen = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dir1);
         System.IO.DriveInfo dirDestino = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dir2);

         System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = dirOrigen.RootDirectory;
         System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirDestinoInfo = dirDestino.RootDirectory;

         System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirOrigenNames = dirOrigenInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
         System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirDestinoNames = dirDestinoInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

         for (int i = 0;i<=(fileDirOrigenNames.Length)-1;i++ )
         {
             System.IO.FileInfo file = fileDirOrigenNames[i];
             for (int j = 0; j <= (fileDirDestinoNames.Length)-1; j++)
             {
                 System.IO.FileInfo file2 = fileDirDestinoNames[j];
                 if (file.Name.Equals(file2.Name))
                 {
                     mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(file.DirectoryName, file2.DirectoryName);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Aquí están los métodos para comparar dos ficheros por propiedades:

```
    static bool compareFilesByProperties(string file1, string file2)
    {
        DateTime fechaCreacion1 = File.GetCreationTime(file1);
        DateTime ultimaModificacion1 = File.GetLastWriteTime(file1);

        DateTime fechaCreacion2 = File.GetCreationTime(file2);
        DateTime ultimaModificacion2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(file2);

        if ((fechaCreacion1.Date.Equals(fechaCreacion2.Date)) &&(ultimaModificacion1.Date.Equals(ultimaModificacion2.Date)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fecha de Creación y última modificación son iguales");
            return true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fecha de Creación o última modificación NO son iguales");
        return false;

    }

    static void mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(string file1, string file2)
    {
        if (compareFilesByProperties(file1, file2)==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Los  {0} y {1} son iguales por fecha de creación y por última modificación",file1, file2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Los archivos {0} y {1} no son iguales por fecha de creación y por última modificación", file1, file2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cual es la pregunta o el problema?

Comment: Diría que el código a simple vista está bien, pero no me hace bien la comparación. Los dos archivos que comparo no son iguales por fecha y al compilar me indica que sí son iguales.

Comment: Pero no estas comparando que sean iguales las fechas, sólo estas comparando el nombre igual en: `if (file.Name.Equals(file2.Name))`

Comment: Bueno, básicamente lo que estas comparando es nombre de archivo. Por qué piensas que te va a decir que no son iguales si no estás comparando las fechas?

Comment: las fechas las comparo en el método  mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(), una vez sepa que los nombres son iguales. Y he comprobado que este método funciona.

Comment: En ese caso,debes mostrarnos ese método, si no no podemos saber que estás haciendo.

Comment: ya lo tenéis, a ver que os parece

Comment: creo que el problema no está ahí, sino en los archivos que me compara, porque no está comparando los 5 archivos que tengo repartidos entre las dos carpetas, hay muchos más. Os copio lo que me sale en consola: Los C:\bootmrg y C:\bootmrg son  iguales \n Los C:\eula1031.txt y C:\eula.1031.txt son iguales... Está cogiendo archivos del propio C:, no del directorio que indico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no estás comparando los archivos que tú crees:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo dirOrigen = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dir1);
System.IO.DriveInfo dirDestino = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dir2);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = dirOrigen.RootDirectory;
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirDestinoInfo = dirDestino.RootDirectory;
```

Estás accediendo al directorio raíz de los directorios que pasas al método (`dirOrigen.RootDirectory`). Quita las dos primeras líneas (no necesitas `DriveInfo` para nada) y modifica estas líneas para obtener los archivos de los directorios que pasas al método:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir1);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirDestinoInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir2);
```

Comment: era eso, muchas gracias por la ayuda, me has salvado jajaja

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que muestras, estas comparando sólo las fechas del `DateTime`, sin las horas, minutos, segundos ni ticks, y creo que tu problema viene de ahí.

Para poder comparar todo eso debes quitar de tu condición el `.Date` y comparar el `DateTime` entero:

```
if ((fechaCreacion1.Equals(fechaCreacion2)) &&(ultimaModificacion1.Equals(ultimaModificacion2)))
```

Comment: he probado y el problema sigue ahí...